# Error: "; expected", can't find where I'm missing it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, public, partial-classes

I'm using a public partial class to extend some LINQ TO SQL Classes, and am getting the aforementioned error for my [first attempt] at adding a weird property, not sure if I'm doing it right. :S

In any case, code follows:

```
public partial class Round
{
    public int PlayersInRound
    {
        get { return this.RoundMembers.Count(); }
    }

    public bool PlayerIsInRound(string sUsername)
    {
        get { return ((from x in this._RoundMembers where x.Member.Email == sUsername select x).Count() >= 1); }
    }
}
```

The VS IDE gives a red underline to the "{" on the third-to-last line, and I'm not sure why. The first added one *seems* to work fine, but I'm not entirely sure it does as I haven't built enough of the site yet, nor do I **really** know how to do TDD as of yet. :P

Thanks a ton, guys! :)

Comment: Wow, nevermind. Looks like _somehow_ I accidentily added an underscore to the this.RoundMembers area, and that's what's throwing it off. I have no idea how that got there .. Now, how can I mark this question closed? xD

Comment: Just accept one of the answers below, and it's 'closed'. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is in the `PlayerIsInRound`: You are mixing a method with a property

remove the `get{}`

```
public bool PlayerIsInRound(string sUsername)
{
    return ((from x in this._RoundMembers where x.Member.Email == sUsername select x).Count() >= 1);
}
```

Comment: Oh, how should I go about doing this, instead, then?

Comment: This fixed my issue, thank you! I'll have to wait around 7 more minutes before I Can mark this complete, though.. I'll leave the tab open so I don't forget! :P